# HockeyApp update and crash popups have no text

Tags: android, hockeyapp

I have HokeyApp integrated into my Android app and it has been working very well for us but recently both the popup prompting the user if they want to report a crash and the popup prompting the user if they would like to update are both just blank white squares.

If you tap on the popups where the buttons would be it acts like you tapped on the button. For example on the update popup I can get it to update by tapping on the popup where the "Show" button would be if you could see it.

I just pushed an update and I am getting a ton of bug reports about this and it looks really bad for my app. Is there a way to customize the popups where someone may have made a change and broken this? Do I need to rely on HokeyApp support to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your code implementing the HockeyApp SDK crash/update features for context?

Comment: I only needed to add the lines `CrashManager.register(this);` and `UpdateManager.register(this);` in the `onCreate` function of my main activity to get these features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your theme colors, especially how `AlertDialog`s are themed.

The buttons are controlled by
`android:buttonBarButtonStyle` - check that its `background` and `textColor` are not the same. Similarly for the alert dialog theme - check that the text appearance there has distinctive foreground and background colors.

Comment: After some testing it looks like this was the issue. We changed the theme to match the client's branding and it's using the primary text color specified there (white), but not the background color. Which colors from the theme that are used in the AlertDialog seems to change depending on the version of Android the client is running, but I haven't fully tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, can only suggest general debugging steps for fixing the empty dialogs problem: check your implementation against documentation, check the SDK version is up-to-date, try to reproduce problem in a blank activity, etc.

However, [HockeyApp docs](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#crashreporting-advanced) say you *can* show your own custom UI for the update dialog, and crash reports can be set to send without prompting the user.